# Blazor Webassembly error when adding project refrence

Tags: .net, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor, .net-5

In my Blazor WebAssembly project I add a project reference to a class library in my soulution. Then I get the following error:

> Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(387, 5): [NETSDK1082] There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

Also the entire project has missing references to System, Microsoft.AspNetCore, ...

This is my project properties where I add my refrence:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Dashboard.Core\Dashboard.Core.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Check the refrencing project and what it uses. I have often just hasty added a classlib and made it .net framework instead of core (now .net). As a second attemt, try change sdk to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Comment: The referencing project is .Net Core. When I change the sdk of the referencing project to 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' I have the same problem

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I had to change my BlazorWebassembly to Web. Not the referencing project. But then I can't run it as BlazorWebassymbly

Comment: I found the problem. In my referering package, I included Identity and this causes the issue